# Any way to prove this identity :$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\frac{H(x)x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} =\delta(x)$?

Tags: dirac-delta, step-function

One of my friend sent me to proof this identity :$\frac{d^m}{dx^m}\frac{H(x)x^{m-1}}{(m-1)!} =\delta(x)$ Where $\delta$ is the dirac delta  function and $H$ is [heaviside step function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html) , I knwo only that [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) of the first order of heaviside step function present dirac function, But i never saw the titled formula with $m$ th derivative , Then does the title identity a well known formula ? and how i can show it ?

Comment: what definition of $\delta$ and derivative are you using?

Comment: delta is dirac delta function

Comment: look this :http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html

Comment: Are you sure of this formula ?  It's well known that $ \frac{d}{dx} H(x) = \delta(0)$, doesn't work for $m=1$ ?

Comment: From there, you see the definition of $\delta$ is $\langle \delta, f \rangle = f(0)$, so what are you using to define the derivative of that?

Comment: No it works for m=1 , look here derivative of heaviside step function ,https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function